# Login page session timeout issue in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, spring-security, session-timeout

How can we make login page sessionless ? I have tried using `<%@page session="false" %>` but it doesn't work if I open a login page and try using page after timeout (specified in web.xml) it won't login because my handshake encryption key stored in session is not available now and session is already invalidated.

How can we tell server not to create session for login page ? I am also using Spring security in my application if that can help.

Comment: If you are using Spring Security it will. by default, use a CSFR token which is stored in the session. If you don't want this disable the CSFR protection and then it should work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Disabling CSRF protection is not an option buddy.. I want to make an exception only for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Make change in web.xml and set session-timeout to `-1`.

```
<session-config>
      <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Now it will never expire.

Comment: It will never expire but other pages will also never expire.... I want to make exception only for the login page..

Comment: @aProgrammer Now in this case you can persist your key some where in db or in local storage.